# Deleting a post by id?

Tags: reactjs

reducer

```
import { COMBINE_POST } from '../Actions/actionType'

const initialState = {
    posts: null,
    users: null,
    comments: null,
    post: null
}

export const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'getPosts':
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.data
            }
        case 'getUsers':
            return {
                ...state,
                users: action.data
            }
        case 'getComments':
            return {
                ...state,
                comments: action.data
            }
        case COMBINE_POST :
            return {
                ...state,
                post: action.payload
            }
        case 'removePost':
                console.log('removepost', state.post.post)
            return {
                ...state,
                post: state.post.post.filter(item => item.id !== 
                 action.payload)
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

action

```
import { COMBINE_POST } from './actionType'

export const fetchPosts = () => {
   return dispatch => {
       fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/`)
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then(res => dispatch({ type: 'getPosts', data: res }))
   }
}

export const fetchUsers = () => {
   return dispatch => {
       fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/`)
           .then(res => res.json())
           .then(res => dispatch({ type: 'getUsers', data: res }))
   }
}

export const fetchComments = () => {
   return dispatch => {
       fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/`)
       .then(res => res.json())
       .then(res => dispatch({ type: 'getComments', data: res }))
   }
}

export const removePost = id => {
   return dispatch => {
       fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${id}`, {
           method: 'DELETE', 
   })
   dispatch({ type: 'removePost', payload: id })
   }
}

export const combimePost = arr => ({ type: COMBINE_POST, payload: arr })
```

component render

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { fetchPosts, fetchUsers, fetchComments, removePost } from '../../Redux/Actions/action'
import { combimePost } from '../../Redux/Actions/action'
import  './newsList.scss'

export const NewsList = () => {

 const dispatch = useDispatch()
 const selector = useSelector(state => state.rootReducer)


 useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(
     fetchPosts()
   )
 }, [])

 useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(
     fetchUsers()
   )
 }, [])

 useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(
     fetchComments()
   )
 }, [])


This is where I combine the post and user id

 useEffect(() => {
   const combinePost = selector.posts?.map(post => ({
      ...post, 
      user: selector.users?.find(user => post.userId === user.id), 
      commetn: selector?.comments?.find(comment => post.id === comment.postId)
     }))
   return dispatch(
     combimePost(
       {
         post: combinePost,
       }
     )
   )
 }, [selector.posts, selector.users, selector.comments])



 return <>
   {selector?.post?.post?.map((res, i) => (
         <div className="card text-center" key={i}>
         <div className="card-header">
         {res.user?.name}
         </div>
         <div className="card-body">
           <h5 className="card-title">{res.title}</h5>
           <p className="card-text">{res.comment?.body}</p>
             <button 
           className="btn btn-outline-danger"
         onClick={() => dispatch(removePost(res.id))}
          >DELETE</button>
         </div>
         <div className="card-footer text-muted">
           
         </div>
       </div>
   )
   )}
 </>
}
```

When a post is deleted, all posts disappear from the page, in the console it shows that the selected post has been deleted, but the page is not rendered, it becomes empty. what is the problem ?
When a post is deleted, all posts disappear from the page, in the console it shows that the selected post has been deleted, but the page is not rendered, it becomes empty. what is the problem ?

Comment: please translate english. problem

Comment: when you delete a post, all posts disappear from the page, and not the selected one, what's the problem?

Comment: my friend . translate post and header by edit.is better for all . thanks

Comment: wrote in more detail and dropped all the code

Comment: very good.if add sample code in codesandbox is great for debugging

Comment: I can't, it gives errors, after all, I threw off all the code, here either someone knows what the problem is and can tell if not

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-architecture-jsvfm     
here is the error in the sunbox

Comment: what's version redux.is saga or ...?

Comment: Using redux-thunk